# How to get specific fields data from string without field labels fetched from image by using tesseract-ocr

Tags: regex, python-2.7, tesseract, string-parsing, python-tesseract

I have written a program that ask for the user to upload the DMV license picture and reads the DMV License details from the uploaded picture using [tesseract ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract). I've got the tesseract part work which does well to some extent. I have got a raw string and now I need to parse that string to fetch user details. The problem is that some fields on DMV license have no lables. Like name, address etc. I need to fetch these details. I can't come up with idea (may be I can use regex but don't know how to get it work?). If someone already did that I'd love to take a look. . Any suggestion would be welcome.

**Image:**
[image: DMV LICENSE PICTURE]

**CODE**
Here is the code to read the uploaded file and get text from image using tesseract.

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

# replace the path with the path to tesseract installation directory on server.
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

@csrf_exempt
def upload_dmv(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        dmv = request.FILES['dmv']
        extracted_data = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(dmv))
        print(extracted_data)
    return HttpResponse(b'OK')
```

**Output**

```
W YORK STALE
DRIVER Ee C{ENeSae
876 071652

BOGADO
PETER,GIOVANNI.

9520 93RD ST FL 2
OZONE PARK, NY 114116

SexM_ Height6'-02" Eyes BRO:
00806/06/1992

Expires 06/06/2018
ENONE
RB

Issued 03/09/2017

Usa

~e-h.

Crecutive Deputy Comminsioner of Motor

Class E
```